# regEX not working in angular form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I am trying to validate phone number with regEX. below is my requirement.
10 digits alpha/numeric, where an Alpha CHAR is in the 4th position (not including hyphen).  For example:  586R410056

   NNN ANN NNNN

   (NNN) ANN NNNN

   NNN-ANN-NNNN

   (NNN) ANN-NNNN

   1NNN ANN NNNN

   1(NNN) ANN NNNN

   1NNN-ANN-NNNN

   1(NNN) ANN-NNNN

   NNN.ANN.NNNN

   (NNN-ANN-NNNN)

I came up with following regEX, but it's not working in angular form.
regEX:

```
^[1]?\s?\(?\d{3}\)?[-.\s]?[a-zA-Z]{1}\d{2}[-.\s]?\d{4}\)?$
```

Comment: Why don't think of use ui-mask directive.. Which will provide the behavior you want..

Comment: First, try `/^1?\s?\(?\d{3}\)?[-.\s]?[a-zA-Z]\d{2}[-.\s]?\d{4}\)?$/` *without `/g` modifier*. Next, try removing `novalidate`. Have a look at [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/IY64HCTYeAFWWcoLLdKg).

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

**Regex**

```
/1?[\ \.\(]?[N]{3}\)?[]\ \-\.][A][N]{2}[\ \-\.][N]{4}\)?/g
```

(Just replace the `N`s with `[0-9]` and `A` with `[0-9a-zA-Z]`).

**Explanation:**

[image: screenshot]

See working example at https://regex101.com/r/dX1lL0/1.